# regex in tcl not working

Tags: regex, tcl

this thing is killing me and i think i am missing very basic concept in tcl regular expressions. i have the following code

```
foreach line $data {
    if {[regexp {^(\#|\s)} $line]} {continue;} else {[lappend $puneet "$line"];}
}
```

So i have variable line which could have a '`#`' as its first character, or a '`\s`' space or the normal alphanumeric char. Now all i want is to create a list of lines that has only alphanumeric characters as its first character.

But the above code doesn't seem to give the desired output due to some syntax issue which i couldn't find. This is very basic but since i am still a rookie in regex, i am not sure if i am missing any brackets in my above expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the last part of your `if` statement:

```
[lappend $puneet "$line"];
```

This will append the contens of line to the variable with the name of the current value of the `punneet` variable. After that, it tries to find a command with the name of the current line, which will probably fail.

Correct is:

```
foreach line $data {
    if {[regexp {^(\#|\s)} $line]} {continue} else {lappend puneet $line}}
}
```

If you are using Tcl 8.6, you could write the entire thing as:

```
set puneet [lmap line $data {if {[regexp {^(\#|\s)} $line]} {continue}; set line}
```

Comment: Ohhhh yup, thanks Johan. and i was trying to find error in the regex. thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You have too many brackets!

```
foreach line $data {
    if {[regexp {^(\#|\s)} $line]} {continue;} else {[lappend $puneet "$line"];}
                                                  ;# ^                       ^ 
}
```

You are evaluating the `$line` when you put square brackets around `lappend`

Also, with `lappend` you shouldn't use the dollar sign.

All the semicolons can be dropped here:

```
foreach line $data {
    if {[regexp {^(\#|\s)} $line]} {continue} else {lappend puneet "$line"}
}
```

Okay, now there are some stuff you could change some more: `#` doesn't need to be escaped and you can use `!` to avoid using `continue` and an `else` block and `$line` doesn't really need to be quoted here as it's the only argument:

```
foreach line $data {
    if {![regexp {^(#|\s)} $line]} {lappend puneet $line}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `lsearch` here instead of a loop:

```
set data {{# one} two { three} #four five { six}}

set puneet [lsearch -all -inline -not -regexp $data {^(?:#|\s)}]    ;# two five
```